# Which scriptures other than the Ramcharitmanas mention that during Shiva Parvati marriage ceremony Ganapaty was worshipped?

Tags: shiva, scripture, ganesha

In the hundredth doha of the Balakanda of Ramcharitmanas it is mentioned that Ganapaty was worshipped during the marriage of Shiva & Parvati.

> मुनी अनुसासन गनपतिहि पूजेउ संभु भवानी ।
>   कोउ सुनी संसय करै जानी सुर अनादि जिए जानी ।।
>
> " At the direction of the sages Sambhu and > Bhavani paid divine honours to Lord 
>   Ganapati. Let no one be puzzled to hear 
>   this; for one should bear in mind that gods have 
>   existed from time without beginning."

Also in Shiva Purana 2.109

> Once Narada had a desire to listen to the 
>   tales of Ganesha. Brahmaji replied- 
>   "There were various Ganeshas in 
>   different Kalpas. During the period of 
>   'Shweta-Kalp', Ganesha was 
>   born to Shiva and Parvati, when they went > to 
>   Kailash mountain shortly after their 
>   marriage.
>  >

■ 1) Are there  any other scriptures which mention about  this incident  ?

■ 2) What is meant by "In Shweta kalpa Ganesh was born to Shiva and Parvati ".
Are there mentions of Ganesha being born to some other parents during any other Kalpas?

Comment: The reference of Lord Ganapati in the shloka of Ramcharitmanas actually refers to Lord Indra. In vedas Indra is referred as Ganpati. Most people mistake it with Lord Ganesha who is actually maa parwati's son. Although Lord Ganesha deserves the same honour as that of Lord Indra but in above shloka the mentioned deity is Lord Indra.

Comment: @Deepeshkumar I think you are wrong... Indra isnt mentioned as Ganapati in Vedas.. There is 1 sloka which refers to Brihaspati by the name Ganapati in Vedas... and furthermore that verse in Ramcharitmanas refers to Ganesh only otherwise below it there wouldnt be verse saying that " *Let no one be puzzled to hear this* "

Comment: @TejasweePokhrel Actually there are Vedic verses that refer to Indra as Ganapati.  But yeah, I agree that the Ramcharitmanas is referring to Ganesha.  In any case, the two main texts that describe the incarnations of Ganesha in different ages are the Ganesha Purana and the Mudgala Purana, but both of them are of dubious authenticity.

Comment: "5. Due to the difference of Kalpas, the story of the birth of Ganesa is told in different ways. According to one account he is born of the great lord. His head looked at by Sanit was cut off and an elephant's head was put on him. 
6. Now we narrate the story of the birth of Gaqeéa in Svetakalpal'å when his head was cut off by the merciful Siva".Chapter 13 birth of Ganesha, Rudrasamhita, Kumarakandam, section 4.

Comment: @The Destroyer Do you know any refrence of Ganesh being born from other than Lord Shiva and Parvati...?

Comment: @Tezz  Footnotes of that Chapter says " Sani (the planet Saturn) is called the evil-øed (Krüradrå), for his glance casts an evil effect. The present context refers to a legend of Pärvati who proud of her son, Ganesa, asked Sani to look at him. Sani looked and the child's head was burnt to ashes. Pärvati felt greatly distressed and Brahmä offered consolation advising her to replace the head with the first she could find and that was an elephant's". But it did not mention which Kalpa this had happened and which purana it is mentioned.

Comment: @The Destroyer There are also other stories... Ganesh manifesting from sweat of Shiva... from Laughter of Shiva... Lord Shiva himself cursing Ganesh to look elephant headed etc...

Comment: @Tezz Ohh.. didn't know them.

Comment: @The Destroyer for eg Varaha Purana in 3.4 tells Ganesh manifesting from sweat of Lord Shiva ..

Comment: @Tezz You can mention this as answer for you second part. This might have happened in previous kalpa. Same stories happen with slight variations in different Kalpas. Unfortunately, many Puranas don't mention **when** a particular story happened.

Comment: @The Destroyer Yeah... In our present Brahma period more than 18000 kalpas has passed...we can't even imagine the variations of the stories

Answer (score 5):

Actually posts are worshipped -  **Manu**, **Indra**, **Saptarisis**, **Vedvyas**, **Ganesh or Ganapati or Mahaganapati**, **Prajapati** are merely posts or titles (who holds the title can be found in Puranas. Few of them are given [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp076.htm) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20779/why-sons-of-lord-shiva-devi-parvati-are-only-worshipped/21646)).

> Ganesh (Head of Ganas, also known as Ganapati or Mahaganapati) is the prominent post/title since beginning or Aadi kaal (hence considered as one of the **Aadi Devas**) and must be worshiped before any other god.

**How Ganesha became 'the first deity to get worshipped in any ritual'?**

As per [Shiva Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/shiva_purana/shiva_severs_ganeshas_head_later_given_elephant_head.php), Lord Ganesha became (got the title) Ganapati/Vighneshwar soon after his head was severed by Lord Shiva as demanded by Goddess Parvati.

As per [Varaha Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/varaha_purana/lord_ganapati.html),

Lord Brahma appeared and requested Lord Shiva by saying-

> 'You should make this divine child, who has manifested from your mouth, the lord of all these Vinayakas. Thus lord Shiva made Ganesh the lord of all the Vinayakas and blessed him- **You will be the first deity to get worshipped in any ritual**.'

As stories are from different different Kalpas, so there are many stories related to Lord Ganesha's birth and how he became 'the first deity to get worshipped in any ritual'. But above two are most famous.

Goddess Lakshmi emerged from Samudra Manthan (Ocean-Churning) but if someone conclude from this that there was no Goddess Lakshmi before that then it's not right. Because earlier than this Goddess Lakshmi was daughter of Khyati and Bhrigu. ***After Indra showed disrespect to her (or sage Durvasa in some stories), she made her abode in the abysmal depth of the sea and later emerged during Samudra Manthan.***

> Maitreya says - "O sage! It is heard that Lakshmi was produced from Ksheersagar during the churning of the sea but you say that Lakshmi was the daughter of Bhrigu and Khyati. How is it possible?"

> Parashar says- "O great Brahmin! Lakshmi who never separates from the Lord is Herself eternal like Him. But still, as you have expressed your doubt, I will narrate you the real story." Read the full story from Vishnu Puran [here](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/vishnu_purana/creation_of_rudra_and_lakshmi.html) and [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp042.htm)

Similarly, Lord Ganesh is an avatar/incarnation of Mahaganapati. Few popular incarnations of Mahaganapati:

> [Source](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/gods/devta/ganesha):

> **MahotkataVinayak**- He was born in Kruta Yuga as son of Kashyap and Aditi. He killed the demons named as Devantak and Narantak.

> **Ganesh**- He was born in Dvaapaara Yuga as the son of Parvati.

**Dhumraketu**- In Kali Yuga, he will be born as Dhumraketu or Dhumravarna and will destroy the Mlecchas, the sinners.

Therefore,

> Lord Ganapti is **Aadi Dev**, he existed even before his [incarnation](http://m.livehindustan.com/astrology/spiritual/story-shiva-parvati-wedding-ganesha-worship-1190157.amp.html) as son of Lord Shiv and Goddess Parvati. [He is there since times immemorial](http://creative.sulekha.com/divine-marriage-of-lord-shiva-and-maa-parvatiji-mahashivratri-23rd-feb_73885_blog) and hence was worshiped by Lord Shiv and Goddess Parvati at the time of their marriage.

**This question is related with the below Question(s):**

[Is Vinayaka an individual or a position like Indra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21785/is-vinayaka-an-individual-or-a-position-like-indra)

[Which puranas contain the story of the contest between Ganesha and Kartikeya for vighnadhipatyam?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22564/which-puranas-contain-the-story-of-the-contest-between-ganesha-and-kartikeya-for)

Comment: Ganapati/Mahaganapati is not a post.

Comment: @moonstar2001 why not? Ganapati = gana + pati => i.e. one who is master/head of all the ganas it is same as Prajapati = praja + pati => head of praja; there are many prajapati other than Daksha

Comment: @moonstar2001 Senapati = sena + pati => head of sena (army); do u think Senapati is not a post/title?

Comment: The only senapati is subramhanya. Only the son of Shiva and parvati was deemed fit to lead the army of the gods. Similarly only Ganesha is lord and master of ganas. With Ganesha and subramhanya, the words ganapati and senapati are proper nouns;not common.

Comment: Another point for you to solidify that ganesha and subramhanya are supreme gods and not posts is their inclusion in the panchayatana and shanmatas (established by Sankaracharya). These matas are not formulated around posts or demigods.

Comment: @moonstar2001 so u mean there was no Senapati before Lord Kartikey then who leaded the battles which happened before his birth?????? I agree he is the best among all Senapatis (Lord Krishna says so in Geeta) but does that mean there was no Senapati for Gods army before him and they used to fight with Asuras without a Senapati?????? Or there was no battle happened before his birth?????

Answer (score 2):

In Ganpati Atharvashirsh it is said त्वं ब्रह्मा त्वं विष्णुस्त्वंरुद्रस्त्वमिन्द्रस्त्वमग्निस्त्वंवायुस्त्वं सूर्यस्त्वं चन्द्रमास्त्वंब्रह्म भूर्भुवस्सुवरोम् ॥
Which means Ganesha is Brahma ,Vishnu ,Indra and all the deties
ADI Shankaracharya also gave the concept of Panch-Parameshwar, which refers to as 5 aspects of Brahm(not Brahma). According to which these 5 deities are Anadi and Anant and all the deties in Santa Dharma are their incarnations or avatars. Panch Parameshwar comprises of Ganpati or Vinayak, Shiv , Vishnu , Devi or Shakti, Hiranyagarbh Brahma or Surya.
According to ADI Shankaracharya there is no difference between these 5 .
There is one Parameshwar, when Parameshwar does Anugrah then Parameshwar is known as Ganpati,when Parameshwar does Nigrah then Parameshwar is known as Devi , when Parameshwar does Creation then Parameshwar is known as Hiranyagarbh Brahma,when Parameshwar does Palan then Parameshwar is known as Vishnu and when Parameshwar does Sanghar then Parameshwar is known as Shiv.

In Vedas Ganpati is referred as

गणानां त्वा गणपतिं हवामहे
कविं कवीनामुपमश्रवस्तमम् ।
ज्येष्ठराजं ब्रह्मणां ब्रह्मणस्पत
आ नः शृण्वन्नूतिभिः सीद सादनम् ॥
Gannaanaam Tvaa Ganna-Patim Havaamahe
Kavim Kaviinaam-Upama-Shravastamam |
Jyessttha-Raajam Brahmannaam Brahmannaspata
Aa Nah Shrnnvan-Uutibhih Siida Saadanam ||

Meaning:
(This Mantra of Rig Veda 2.23.1 is addressed to Brihaspati / Brahmanaspati)
1: Among the Ganas (Group of Prayers), to You Who are the Ganapati (Lord of Prayers), we Offer our Sacrificial Oblations,
2: You are the Wisdom of the Wise and Uppermost in Glory,
3: You are the foremost King of the Prayers, presiding as the Lord of the Prayers (Brahmanaspati),
4: Please come to us by Listening to our Invocation and be Present in the Seat of this Sacred Sacrificial Altar (to charge our Prayers with Your Power and Wisdom).
And in Various Puranas such as Brahmvaivart Puran (Ganpati khand),Mudgal Puran, Ganesh Puran and many other Vedic and Puranic documents refer him as Parabrahmparamatma.