# Why sons of Lord Shiva & Devi Parvati are only worshipped?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, worship, lakshmi, parvati

As we know Lord Ganesha and Lord Kartikeya are sons of Lord Shiva & Devi Parvati. Every Hindu know this. But there is no source which would tell who are sons of Lord Vishnu and Devi Lakshmi. [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/646/10089) is a answers about son of Lord Vishnu and Devi Lakshmi. Bit confusing.

Son of Lord Ram & Devi Sita ⇒ Luv, Kush

Son of Lord Krishna & Devi Rukmani ⇒ Pradyumna.

But there is no worship for them or son of any other Gods other than Ganesha 
and Kartikeya.

Why Lord Shiva & Devi Parvati's sons are worshipped? And sons of other Gods are not worshipped like Ganesha and Kartikeya.

Comment: Luv, Kush and Pradyumna are son of Incarnations, not of Lord Directly. Although I didn't meant that Lord's sons will be worshiped without any reason. And there is a reason and full story about worshiping Ganesha primarily(Pratham pujya). And Kartikay worshiped coz He killed many asuras to protect mankind. To be worshiped you have to show some qualities that are worthy of worship in world. And both Ganesha and Kartikay showed that already. This is the reason they are being worshiped.

Comment: That is because they are worthy of worship. The other (sons u mentioned) are not. Also Lord Ganesha and Lord Karthikeya are Gods unlike lava-kusha who were human beings. While Ganesha is one of the pancha devatas- 5 most significant Hindu Deities, Karthikeya is the 6th important one.

Comment: Well Haihaya was also Son of Vishnu and Lakshmi

Answer (score 4):

These sons/daughters of other Gods/Goddesses are also worshipped :

> - **Aiyappa** - son of Mohini (avatar of Lord Vishnu) and Lord Shiv
> - **Yam** - son of Surya/Sun God
> - **Yami** or Yamuna river - daughter of Surya/Sun God
> - **Shani** - son of Surya/Sun God
> - **Daksha** - son of Lord Brahma
> - [Goddess Laxmi's sons](http://www.drikpanchang.com/hindu-goddesses/lakshmi/lakshmi-children/goddess-lakshmi-sons-names.html)
> - **Narad** - son of Lord Brahma
> - Lord Brahma's sons who are included in **Saptarisis**
> - **Hanuman** - son of Vayu/Wind God, however Lord Hanumanaji himself is considered as Rudravtar
> - **Ashvins** or Ashwini Kumaras - sons of Surya/Sun God

Also, all the sons of Lord Shiv are not worshipped:

> [Andhaka](https://mdaily.bhaskar.com/news/JM-MYTH-andhaka-shiva-story-5483599-PHO.html?seq=6) (son of Lord Shiv) is considered as notorious.

Actually posts are worshiped and so the one who hold the post. **Ganesh** (Head of Ganas, also known as Ganapati) is the prominent post since beginning or Aadi kaal (hence considered as one of the Aadi Devas) and must be worshiped before any other god.

Even as per Ramcharitmanas, Lord Shiv and Goddess Parvati worshiped Ganesh at the time of their marriage:

> मुनी अनुसासन गनपतिहि पूजेउ संभु भवानी ।
>   कोउ सुनी संसय करै जानी सुर अनादि जिए जानी ।।

As per [Shiv Purana (1.2.109)](http://hinduonline.co/Scriptures/Puranas/ShivaMahaPurana.html):

> There were various Ganeshas in different Kalpas. During the period of 'Shweta-Kalp', Ganesha was born to Shiva and Parvati, when they went to Kailash mountain shortly after their marriage.

**Kartikey** is worshiped because he became [the chief commander or General](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-10-24/) of Gods' Army.

Similarly, sons of Surya, **Yam**, **Shani** and **Ashvins** (or Ashwini Kumaras) are also widely worshiped because they hold prominent titles like God of Death, God of Justice and doctors of gods respectively. **Daksha** and **Narad**, sons of Lord Brahma who hold the title of **Prajapati** and **Devrishi** respectively are also worshipped.

Each manvantar is ruled over by a **Manu** (a post not a name). In the present kalpa, six manvantaras have already passed and the names of the six Manus who ruled were Svayambhu, Svarochish, Uttam, Tamas, Raivat and Chakshush. The name of the seventh Manu, who rules over the seventh manvantar of the present kalpa, is **Vaivasvat**. The titles of the seven great sages (Saptarishi) as well as the title of **Indra** change from manvantar to manvantar. In current manvantar, Indra's name is **Puranadar**. In next Manvantar, these posts will be changed e.g. by the grace of Lord Vishnu, Virochan's son **Bali** will occupy the throne of Indra (according to [Vishnu Puran](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp076.htm)).

> Even Bali (**son of a Ashur**) will become Indra (worthy of worship) in next Manvantar. It really doesn't matter whose sons are worshipped and whose sons are not. Anyone who hold the title/post is worshipped no matter whether he is son of a mighter God or a Asura. If he doesn't hold post/title is not worshipped even he is son of a mighter God (e.g. Karna, **son of Surya/Sun God**). Originally described as the chief of evil spirits in Vedic-era texts, **Kubera** acquired the title 'God of Wealth' later and then people started worshiping him and he is depicted as demigod in later texts such as the Puranas and the Epics.

Comment: I'm not sure if Daksha, Aswini Kumaras are worshiped. But people usually pray Navagrahas.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Ashwini Kumaras are worshipped..many Richas in Rigveda are dedicated to them..Daksha became Prajapati for some time...There r two lists for 33 koti (type) Devas, 12 Aditya, 8 Vasus, 11 Rudras are common but one list consider 2 Ashwini Kumaras and another Prajapati and Indra...

Comment: I meant i'm not sure if they are worshiped by present day Hindus.

Answer (score 2):

Stanza 12 of ***Sri Suktam*** comprises of these lines:

> आपः सृजन्तु स्निग्धानि चिक्लीत वस मे गृहे | नि च देवीं मातरं श्रियं
>   वासय मे खुले ||

O Chikleeta reside in my house and please bring your mother Sri Devi with all her prosperity to stay with me.

Chikleeta is referred to in some scriptures as the son of Sri Devi (Lakshmi) and at Tirupathi Tirumala Devasthanam 'Sri Suktam' is chanted without fail every morning after the Suprabatham. Hence, prayers are sent to Chikleeta, son of Lakshmi, daily. He too is prayed to but not worshipped like Ganesha son of Parvati.

Similarly there is no worshipping of Kartikeya per se.  Prayers are offered to him, but there is no worship per se.  Of course there are temples dedicated to him.  but there are no temples dedicated to Chikleeta.

Some smritis also enumerate Manmatha, God of Love as son of Lakshmi, but this ma be a misconception due the belief, that Pradyumna, the son of Sree Krishna and Rukmini is Manmatha.

Comment: Pradyumna being son of Krishna is not misconception. It is mentioned in Puranas.

Comment: My comment is connected to the earlier part of the statement  - MANMATHA IS CONSIDERED A SON OF LAKSHMI - this may be a misconception since Pradyumna is Manamtha reborn - not that Pradumyna son of Krishna is a misconception.

Comment: @SureshRamaswamy Friend I'm asking why the r not worshiped. And even we don't know the name of son of any other god. Till date I thought Bala (Strength) and Utsaha (Energy) are son of Lord Vishnu and Devi Lakshmi. But even there is no fix info on it. Like we know that Ganesha and Kartikeya are son of Lord Shiv and Devi Parvati.