# Did Krishna marry Rukmini at age of 8?

Tags: krishna, skanda-purana

[image]

I've been told that God Krishna married Rukmini when she was 8 and consummated at same age as per in Skanda Purana. Can I get the right interpretation for this?

Comment: Can you pls mention the exact Khand and Chapter name where this story is mentioned or mention the source from where you are reading this so this can be verified with other versions of Skanda Purana?

Comment: @YDS Skanda Purana Avantya Khanda, Reva Khanda, Chapter 142, verses 13 and 18 (it’s mentioned below in the pic)

Answer (score 7):

Not a chance.
The chapter from bhagwat puran gives an answer to this:—

> **BHAGWATA PURANA. CANTO 10.52.38**
>
> A fter the Supreme One who for the
>   sake of His pastimes assumes His bodies,
>   thus had asked these questions, the
>   brahmin related everything to Him. (37)
>   'S'rî Rukminî told me: 'Oh Most Beautiful
>   One of all the Worlds, I heard about Your
>   qualities. For all who listen and whom
>   You have entered through the openings of
>   their ears, You thus remove the distress of
>   their bodies. To those who have eyes, the
>   sight of Your beauty constitutes the
>   complete fulfillment of their life's
>   purpose. Therefore I have without any
>   shame devoted my mind to You Acyuta!
>   (38) **Who oh Mukunda, compares to Your
>   greatness, Your lineage, character, beauty,
>   knowledge, youth, property and
>   influence? Which sober and marriageable
>   girl of a noble birth would, coming of
>   age, not choose You for her husband, oh
>   lion among men, oh You who fills the
>   mind of every member of society with joy?**
>   (39) I thus have chosen Your good Self, oh
>   dear Lord, for my husband. I offer myself
>   hereby to You as Your wife oh Omnipotent
>   One. Please accept me! May the king of
>   Cedi [S'is'upâla], who like a jackal wants
>   to steal away the portion belonging to the
>   king of the animals, never touch what is
>   allotted to the [real] hero. (40) When I
>   sufficiently have worshiped the Supreme
>   Personality of Godhead, the Lord, by the
>   performance of pious works, with
>   sacrifices, charity, observances and vows,
>   by honoring the gods, the gurus and the
>   brahmins and with other activities, may
>   [Krishna] the elder brother of Gada [ 9.24:
>   46] then [please] come and take my hand
>   and not the son of Damaghosa or others
>   like him? (41) Come tomorrow when the
>   marriage takes place, unseen to Vidarbha,
>   oh Invincible One. Fight surrounded by
>   Your officers then to crush the armed
>   resistance of the kings of Caidya and
>   Magadha and next, as the reward for Your
>   valor, marry me in the râkshasa style [by
>   taking me with You]. (42) You may
>   wonder how, with me moving within my
>   quarters, You can carry me away without
>   killing my relatives. Let me tell You how:
>   the day before there is a large ceremonial
>   procession outside [the palace] for the
>   presiding deity of the family. In that
>   ceremony the new bride approaches the
>   goddess Girijâ [ Ambikâ in her temple].
>   (43) Great souls like [S'iva] the husband
>   of Ûma, in order to overcome their own
>   ignorance, long to bathe in the dust of
>   Your lotus feet. When I, oh Lotus-eyed
>   One, cannot obtain Your mercy, I should,
>   being weakened by vows, give up my life
>   to attain You [only] after hundreds of
>   births.' (44) The brahmin ended with:
>   'This is the confidential message I bring
>   you, oh Lord of the Yadus, please consider
>   what needs to be done right now in this
>   matter.'

"Which sober and marriageable girl of a noble birth would, coming of age, not choose You for her husband" these verses give explanation and the marriageable girls in india ready to marridge can not anyhow "8".

source:— http://bhagavata.org/canto10/chapter52.html

**UPDATE**

**HARIVAMSA PARVA PROOF**

> shvo bhAvini vivAhe cha rukmiNI
>   niryayau bahiH |
>   chaturyujA rathenaindre
>   devatAyatane shubhe ||2-59-33
>
> Saying that the marriage can be
>   held tomorrow, rukmiNI went out
>   to the auspicious temple, on the
>   day of jyeShTha star (aindre - see
>   nIlakaNTha commentary), in a
>   chariot yoked with four horses.
>
> indrANImarchayiShyantI
>   kR^itakautukama~NgalA |
>   dIpyamAnena vapuShA balena
>   mahatA vR^itA ||2-59-34
>
> She, with a sparkling body,
>   surrounded by a great army,
>   wearing the auspicious head band,
>   went to worship indrANI.
>
> tAM dadarsha tadA kR^iShNo
>   lakShmIM sAkShAdiva sthitAm |
>   rUpeNAgryeNa sampannAM
>   devatAyatanAntike ||2-59-35
>
> kR^iShNa saw her near the temple
>   as though lakShmI herself was
>   stationed. She was endowed with a
>   beautiful form.
>
> vahnireva shikhAM dIptAM mAyAM
>   bhUmigatAmiva |
>   pR^ithivImiva gaMbhIrAmutthitAM
>   pR^ithivItalAt ||2-59-36
>
> She was blazing like a flame of fire,
>   as an illusion on earth, as the
>   beautiful and majestic (goddess)
>   earth arising out of earth.
>
> marIchimiva somasya saumyAM
>   strIvigrahAm bhuvi |
>   shrImivAgryAM vinA padmaM
>   bhaviShyAM shrIsahAyinIm |
>
> She was beautiful as though the
>   gentle rays of moon has taken the
>   form of woman on earth. She was
>   like lakShmI leaving the lotus. She
>   was to assist (kR^iShNa) as shrI of
>   future.
>
> kR^iShNena manasA dR^iShTAM
>   durnirIkShyAM surairapi ||2-59-37
>   shyAmAvadAtA sA
>   hyAsItpR^ithuchArvAyatekShaNA |
>
> She who was difficult to be seen
>   even by deva-s, was seen by
>   kR^iShNa with his mind. **She was
>   of sixteen years old. She was of
>   white complexion. Her eyes were
>   long and beautiful.**

sourse:— http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_059.html

Comment: Where is it proved on above passage that Rukmini wasn't Eight years old?..

Comment: if two puranas disagree, is interpolation the only explanation?

Comment: " Which sober
and marriageable girl of a
noble birth would, coming of
age, not choose You for her
husband " these verses give explanation and all the marriageable girl in india ready to marridge can not anyhow "8". and SK sorry, but the thing which is not accepted anywhere else and specially the puran which is related to that god so what i should say. sorry if i hurt you.

Comment: @Fierce Lord - it is difficult to say what content is interpolated.  And what is the criterion for "not interpolated"?  There is universal agreement among scholars that ALL puranas were added to over centuries.  And there is strong evidence that Srimad Bhagavata purana is bogus - the real bhagavata purana is the devi bhagavata purana.  And whats the point of adding the gutter language about Siva - it has nothing to do with the question of the post.

Comment: @SK i am not against lord shiva i can't even think for dooing that but i thought that a purana which is dedicated to lord krishna only i should take the story answer from there and yes, they were interpolated over centuries and i don't think that child marridge was there at time of mahabharata as rukmani devi is evidenced in both mahabharata and harivamsa parva.

Comment: Bhagavata Purana says Rumini developed breast. Do 8 year old girls develop breast?

Comment: This is not an answer. Nowhere proved that Rukmini wasn't 8 years old.

Comment: @ Parikshitha i am proving that rukamani devi was not of 8 years.

Comment: Your answer from harivamsa Purana is only proving rukmini was not 8 years old. Then what about skanda Purana? Any translation mistakes?

Comment: @Parikshitha By any means is it clear that Skanda Purana tells the 5000 years old (I mean Swet-Varaha Kalpa/7th Manvantara/28th Dwapara Yuga) story of Lord Krishna and not from some other Kalpa/Manavantara/Yuga? If stories are from different timelines in Skanda Purana and Bhagavata Purana then they may vary...For example, Lord Ganesha's birth story is completely different in Shiva Purana and Varaha Purana https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22564/which-puranas-contain-the-story-of-the-contest-between-ganesha-and-kartikeya-for/22621#22621

Comment: check the sanskrit verses of harivamsa describing rukmiNI - they dont seem to mention sanskrit word for sixteen . Seems like 16 is tranlsation error.

Answer (score 5):

In harivamsa purana, it is very clearly mentioned that rukmini had large and prominenet breast and fully developed hips before marrying krishna, which an 8 year old doesn't has, and she is also referred to as a woman and not as a child and below is the proof for my claim (i.e. that rukmini was a fully grown maiden before marrying krishna) :

First, I will post those sanskrit verses (from harivamsa puran) which talks of the physical appearance (plump breast and swelling hips) of Rukmini, in addition to that I have also given the meaning  of those  sanskrit words from the verses which gives the required physical description and the sanskrit verse where she is referred to as a woman (damsel) and at the end, I have posted the direct english translation of these verses.

I will now post the  sanskrit verse which says that rukmini has large breast :

harivamsa puran, vishnu parva, अध्याय 59 श्लोक 38 ;  2-59-38

```
      श्यामावदाता स ह्यासीत् पृथुचार्वायतेक्षणा। ताम्रौष्ठनयनापांगी पीनोरुजघनस्तनी।।38।।
```

meaning of the last word :

i) पीनोरुजघनस्तनी - having a large and prominent breast

link for the sanskrit dictionary to verify the meaning :

https://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&tran_input=pinorujaga

link for the verse in sanskrit :

https://hi.krishnakosh.org/%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3/%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B6_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3_%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%81_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5_(%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%A4)_%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF_59_%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%95_36-40

i will now post the verse which says that she is called as a woman :

harivamsa puran, vishnu parva, अध्याय 59 श्लोक 39 ;  2-59-39

```
           बृहती चारुसर्वांगी तन्वी शशिसितानना। ताम्रतुंगनखी सुभ्रूर्नीलकुंजितमूर्धजा।।39।।
```

meaning :

i) तन्वी -  slender or delicate women

link for the sanskrit dictionary to verify the meaning :

https://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&direct=au&script=hk&tran_input=%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%80

link for the verse in sanskrit :

https://hi.krishnakosh.org/%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3/%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B6_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3_%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%81_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5_(%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%A4)_%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF_59_%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%95_36-40

and Now I will post that verse which says that rukmini has developed hips :

harivamsa puran, vishnu parva, अध्याय 59 श्लोक 40 ;  2-59-40

```
         अत्यर्थे रूपत: कान्ता पीनश्रोणिपयोधरा। तीक्ष्णशुक्लै: समैर्दन्तै : प्रभासद्भिरलंकृता।।40।।
```

meaning :

i) पीनश्रोणिपयोधरा - having swelling hips and breast

link for the sanskrit dictionary to verify the meaning :

https://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&direct=au&script=hk&tran_input=%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%AF%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE

link for the verse in sanskrit :

https://hi.krishnakosh.org/%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3/%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B6_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3_%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%81_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5_(%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%A4)_%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF_59_%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%95_36-40

and finally I will post the verses from 2-59-35 to 2-59-40, directly translated into english and the source is also posted below :

Krishna saw, near the temple, Rukshmini, the best of beauties, like unto the burning flame of fire, as if she were the goddess of illusions descended on earth, or the goddess earth herself coming out of the nether region, or the very goddess Shri (the goddess of prosperity) the foremost of damsels, gentle like the rays of the moon, and separated from her lotus, coming down on earth as his wife. That damsel of dark-blue hue and large eyes, Rukshmini, was seated on a car. And though the gods even could not see her with their mind Krishna could see her. Her lips, eyes and the corners were coppery, thighs, hips and breast were plump, her body was tall but thin and beautiful; her countenance was like the moon, her nails were red; eye-brows were charming, hairs were curling and black and her beauty was highly picturesque. Her face was beautified by rows of equal and white teeth (35–40).

source :
https://www.gutenberg.org/files/61937/61937-h/61937-h.htm#chapter-cxvvi-an-account-of-rukshmi-krishna-takes-away-rukshmini

so, it can be concluded that rukmini was a fully grown maiden before she was married to krishna.
since, harivamsa parva (puran) is also a supplement to mahabharat, therefore it is highly authentic and important.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! Since you’re new it is recommended to have a look at the help centre on how to answer as well as [Guidelines for new users answering](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). So for example as you said Harivamsa Parva, it would be appropriate if you could quote the exact verse and verse number and mention which purana the Harivamsa Parva comes in, because not everyone will know. For more help on site working you can contact TheLittleNaruto in [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism). Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In Hindus there is a thing called second birth.in past time age girls age were also calculated as after second birth which happens around  10-11 years after birth.like janeu sanskar they have something same for girls too so 6 years can be true but really it would be 16-17.10+6=16.
Thank you

Comment: Yes you are right Harivamsa mentions 16 years old. If you could please tell what is the thing prescribed for girls? Is it janeu sanskar only? If not how’s it different?

Comment: Hello, please backup your answer with references.

Answer (score 3):

It's very much clear from that, almost every Purana describes Devi Rukmini as a grown-up lady. For instance, this extract from the Bhagavata Purana-

> तां देवमायामिव धीरमोहिनीं सुमध्यमां कुण्डलमण्डिताननाम् । श्यामां
> नितम्बार्पितरत्नमेखलां व्यञ्जत्स्तनीं कुन्तलशङ्कितेक्षणाम् ।
>
> Rukmiṇī appeared as enchanting as the Lord’s illusory potency, who
> enchants even the sober and grave. Thus the kings gazed upon her
> virgin beauty, her shapely waist, and her lovely face adorned with
> earrings. Her hips were graced with a jewel-studded belt, her breasts
> were just budding, and her eyes seemed apprehensive of her encroaching
> locks of hair.[1]

A description of Rukmini from chapter 60, Vishnu Parva, Harivamsa Purana

> 35-40. Krishna saw, near the temple, Rukshmini, the best of beauties,
> like unto the burning flame of fire, as if she were the goddess of
> illusions descended on the earth, or the goddess earth herself coming out
> of the nether region, or the very goddess Shri (the goddess of
> prosperity) the foremost of damsels, gentle like the rays of the moon,
> and separated from her lotus, coming down on earth as his wife. That
> damsel of dark-blue hue and large eyes, Rukshmini, was seated on a
> car. And though the gods even could not see her with their mind
> Krishna could see her. Her lips, eyes, and the corners were coppery,
> thighs, hips and breast were plump, her body was tall but thin and
> beautiful; her countenance was like the moon, her nails were red;
> eye-brows were charming, hairs were curling and black, and her beauty
> was highly picturesque. Her face was beautified by rows of equal and
> white teeth.[2]

This description is enough to tell that She was a young maiden who had already reached puberty, not some eight-year-old child. And how could a little kid write a letter to her lover and ask him to kidnap her? So her minimum age would have been sixteen.

Now, this eight-year-old thing was taken from the Skanda Purana. This screenshot was being circulated on the internet to show that Rukmini was eight years old during Her marriage.

On the basis of this single line, people claim that Lord Krishna is a pedophile! The story is narrated in brief. So Rukmini writing letter to Krishna is not present and the story directly jumps to the marriage episode.

According to the screenshot itself, Rukmini was betrothed to Shishupala at eight, not married, and betrothed means promised.

But how can I be so sure? Let's see what happens next.

> Chapter 142, Revā-khaṇḍa, Skanda Purana[3]
>
> ततः प्रदोषसमये रुक्मिणी काममोहिनी । सखीभिः सहिता याता
> पूर्बहिश्चाम्बिकार्चने ॥ २५ ॥
>
> At the time of dusk, Rukmiṇī, the bride of seductive charms, went out
> of the city accompanied by her female companions for the worship of
> Aṃbikā. [Verse 5.3.142.25]

When She goes for Gauri Pujan, an eight-year-old Rukmini is described as 'kāmamohinī' - one who can enchant even cupid.

Leave this, see the next verse

> सापश्यत्तत्र देवेशं गोपवेषधरं हरिम् । तं दृष्ट्वा मोहमापन्ना कामेन
> कलुषीकृता ॥ २६ ॥
>
> There she saw Hari, the Lord of Devas, in the guise of a cowherd. On
> seeing him, she was excited by the god of Love and became completely
> fascinated. [Verse 5.3.142.26]

On seeing Krishna in the guise of a cowherd, Devi Rukmini (an eight-year-old one) gets excited by Cupid.

Okay, so you expect this behavior from a kid?

The conclusion is either there is some error in the translation or a later addition or it is the twice-born age. Devi Rukmini was never eight years old or 13–14, She was a mature grown-up lady

***And you know what, it is a translation error***

> ततः सा कालपर्यायादष्टवर्षा व्यजायत । पूर्वोक्तं चैव
> तद्वाक्यमशरीरिण्युदीरितम् ॥ १३ ॥
>
> tataḥ sā kālaparyāyādaṣṭavarṣā vyajāyata | pūrvoktaṃ caiva
> tadvākyamaśarīriṇyudīritam || 13 ||
>
> Verse 5.3.142.13

**Here's the verse and the error-**

It's not 'Ashtvarsha' in the verse but "Adashta Varsha". This 'Ad' if ignored, become 8 years otherwise its twice the age of eight that's sixteen.

Answer (score 1):

You have clearly ignored "aad". It is Adashta Varsha not ashta varsha. Check original verse.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the translation is very correct, no one has given any good refutation of Skanda Purana's translation. I am no expert, bit have been able to understand what some of the original Sanskrit words meant.

The Sanskrit words for the statement that she was eight years old are like this, Englishmeanings in brackets are mine:

*Sa(she)kala(time)prayaya(course)aad(?)ashtavarsha* (**eight years**).

Sanskrit source is here, check page number 182 (the Devanagari is labelled 902 in Nepali variant): http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/puranas/skanda_purana/skanda_purana_05avanti_03reva.pdf

Please note that the previous statement was about her birth and her being named Rukmini, so even if its referring to passage of eight years, the translation is basically correct: *Yat Survantilkojanmanasahbharat. Tat sa Rukmininambrahmine kirttatada.*

The English translation seems correct or close, and the Part 15 of the translation by Sanskrot scholars G.P. Bhatt, ‎Jagdish Lal Shastri, ‎Ganesh Vasudeo Tagare too mentions it as such.

The translation of Harivamsa used here claiming Rukmini was 16 during marriage is incorrect.

There is no Sanksrit word for sixteen mentioned in the transliteration: "shyAmAvadAtA sA hyAsItpR^ithuchArvAyatekShaNA". See here for comparison of Sanksrit words for sixteen:

http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=sixteen&direct=au

The Bhagwata Purana is based on mere belief that a mature age was the age of marriage for Hindu girls.

That is false as Manusmriti says even little girls can be married. The Puranas cited here were all written after Manusmriti.

Of course it is not impossible that there may be various versions about her age.