# Did Parvathi ji die ? In which Yugas did Shiv marry Sati and Parvathy?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, parvati

1. Did Parvathi ji die ?
2. In which Yugas did Shiva marry Sati and in which Yuga he married Parvathy ?

Comment: Obviously NOT. She's the great goddess. There's a mention of 'for how long will she live', though. Don't know what does that even mean though.

Comment: Parvati is The eternal Mother? How can she die? It's never possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's totally illogical, how can the universe loss its mother. Irs purely non-sensical thinking.

Let's see What **Skanda Purana 7:1:19:59-62** actually
says.:

> *तावद्वियुक्तोऽहं देवि त्वया मुक्तोऽभवं पुरा ।
> यावद्वराहकल्पस्य चाक्षुषस्यान्तरं प्रिये ॥ ५९ ॥*
>
> *59. Thus bereaved of **you** formerly, O my beloved, I was separated from **you** till the Cākṣuṣa Manvantara of the Vārāhakalpa.*
>
> *एकविंशो मनुश्चायं कल्पे वाराहसंज्ञके ।
> कल्पेकल्पे महादेवि भवेन्नामान्तरं तव ॥ ६० ॥*
> *60. This is the twenty-first Manu (i.e. beginning from Svāyaṃbhuva of Pitṛkalpa and ending with Cākṣuṣa of Vārāha Kalpa) in the Kalpa called Vārāha. O great goddess, in every Kalpa you will have a different name.*
>
> *अस्मिन्कल्पे तु वाराहे हिमवत्तपसार्ज्जिते ।
> संभूता पार्वती देवि चाक्षुषस्यांतरे गते ॥ ६१ ॥*
>
> *61. In this Vārāha Kalpa, O goddess, you became Pārvatī obtained by Himavān through his penance, when the Cākṣuṣa Manvantara has passed off.*
>
> *ब्रह्मणो दिनमेकं तु षण्मासेन तवावधिः ।
> त्वं वियुक्ता मया सार्द्धं दक्षकोपेन भामिनि ॥ ६२ ॥*
>
> *62. **O beautiful lady, due to the anger of Dakṣa you had to be separated from me for the duration of a day of Brahmā.** Your span of life is the period of his six months.*

Again, in the **same chapter verse 26** says that she did penance to get Lord Shiva for crores and crores of years.

> *देव्युवाच ।*
> पंचाग्निनोपसन्तप्ता वर्षकोटीरनेकधा ।
> तत्तपः सफलं जातं मेऽद्य देव जगत्पते ॥ २६ ॥*
>
> *The Devī said.:*
> *26. I performed penance in which I got myself scorched by five fires **for many crores of years.** O Lord, O Lord of the universe, that penance has become fruitful today.*

So, what this suppose to mean, that she spent almost half of her life doing penance only.? I guess not.

Skanda Purana has many such miss-translations like mentioned in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22590/20968) question it is asking about Mata Rukmani being getting attracted and marrying Lord Krishna at the age of 8 years. I mean Really.? 8 years old kid don't understand such things. She was 8*2=16 as mentioned in Harivamsa Parva of MahaBharata. Also, many answers there corrected the translation also. Just like i am doing here. Prd..

Now, let's see.:

> **ṣaṇmāsena = san + māsā + ena.**
>
> Where,
>
> san = 6.
>
> māsā = months.
>
> ena = **then/at that time/this/now/at this time/it/he/she, etc, etc, etc.**

So, the correct translation should be something like this.:

> *ब्रह्मणो दिनमेकं तु षण्मासेन तवावधिः ।
> त्वं वियुक्ता मया सार्द्धं दक्षकोपेन भामिनि ॥ ६२ ॥*
>
> ***62. O beautiful lady, due to the anger of Dakṣa you (as Sati) had to be separated from me for the duration of a day of Brahmā. And at that time, your (viz Sati's) life span was six Brahma's months (as you had to abandon your body early).***

**Conclusion.:** Shiv-Shakti are eternal and immortal power couples.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: I don't know if I have comprehension problem but in your answer itself you have written that Shiva was separated from his wife for a duration of day of Brahma. And that she had to abandon her body i.e. she died.  Means for that day of Brahma when Shiva was not with his wife , Universe must have been without its mother.

Comment: 1st of all Shiva is not exactly KalAgniRudra. He is Shiva's saguna and full parcel form same as Uma is not exactly Parvati or Sati they are her Saguna full avatar. Even though Mata sati died the material form viz Shakti remains and took birth as Parvati and This Mata Parvati will remain till the Pralaya and then every thing including Brahma Vishnu Rudra and all Prakritis will merge back into Shiva-Shakti nirguna form to again get recreated again. For more u can see [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53757/20968) answer of mine. Moral of the Story, Universal parents are Sanatana.Babye.

Comment: || ॐ तत् सत् ||