# What will happen after Parvati die ? Was Sati born in the first Yug of First day of Brahma?

Tags: shiva, parvati, sati

Sati is the first wife of Shiva . When was she born ? Was she born in the first Satyuga of first day of Brahman.
Since Brahma is currently 51 years old. So, about 1,85,03,310 Yugas (approximate) have occured till now. [I have calculated this.](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Kalpa-Manvantara-and-Yuga-in-Hindu-mythology/answer/Sumit-Shrivastava-6)

So, When was Sati born ? Was she born in the first SatYuga of 1,85,03,310 Yugas that have occured.

[Parvati is currently 6 months old.(Brahma time)](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21039/23709) And she will live for 6 Brahma months more
What will happen after she die ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, i think i have already [answered](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53701/20968) to a similar question of yours.

Anyways, further adding a verse from the **Soundarya Lahari** of Jagat Guru Sri Adi Shankaracharya Maharaja ji.:

> *Virincih panchatvam vrajati harir apnoti virathim Vinasam kinaso bhajati dhanado yati nighanam; Vitandri mahendri vithathir api sammeelita-drsa Maha-samhare smin viharati sati tvat-patirasau. 26..*
>
> ***The creator Brahma reaches the dissolution, The Vishnu attains death, The god of death (Yama) even dies, Kubera the lord of wealth expires, The Indras close their eyes one after one, And attain the wake less sleep, During the final deluge, But you my chaste mother (Uma), Play with your consort the Sadashiva.***

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: When did Sati marry Shiva ? How old was Brahma then ? Did Sati marry Shiva in the first Satyug of this MahaKalp ? i.e. when Brahma was less than one day old ?

Comment: Also this Soundrya Lahiri book can't be considered authentic. It is illogical to think that Shiva will survive after Brahma dies. Because Shiva is the son of Brahma. So, When Brahma will be born again in next MahaKalp , he will again give birth to Shiva again.

Comment: Also if both Shiva and Parvati survive the death of Brahma , then how will Sati marry Shiva in next MahaKalp ?

Comment: What you r saying here is illogical. Soundarya Lahari is totally authentic. As in shiva puran its given 1 day of brahma is a kalpa. 1 day of vishnu is 10 years of brahma, i day of rudra 8s 10 years of vishnu and 1 breath of sadashiva is the life time of the tridevs and each lives for 100 yrs according to their own calculation. And the same deity again takes birth n keeps on taking it.

Comment: But If Shiva and Parvati don't die even after death of Brahma , then how ill Sati marry Shiva  in next MahaKalp ?

Comment: Brahma, Vishnu, Rudra creates each other in every kalpa. Sometimes brahma creates vishnu and rudra, sometimes vishnu creates rudra brahma and sometimes rudra creates brahma vishnu and so on.

Comment: Rudra, parvati, lakshmi, vishnu, brahma, saraswati all dies in maha kalpa. and after taking birth the trinity recreates everything.

Comment: Parvati and Sati marries Shiva or Rudra ?

Comment: As for brahma, he is the grandfather of sati and everyone's calculation of age is different from each other as they have their own time. For example a fly will live for some hours which is its whole life time but for us this time period is insignificant.

Comment: They marries the kailash deity Shankara/Rudra.

Comment: Who is Uma ? Is She female form of Vishnu ?  You have written it in your [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53757/23709) answer. So, Shiva and female form of Vishnu remain alive at the end of MahaKalp ?

Comment: The thing is you are seeing all as individuals but i am explaining them as 1 single entity. Yes, Vishnu is the male form of Uma because he is present in the left side of Shiva so he is prakriti tattva and Shiva is purusha tattva. But, because left side of shiva belongs to both shiva and and uma so vishnu though is uma is male. Basically vishnu is ganesha.

Comment: Vishnu is Ganesh ? How ? Yeah I have heard that Vishnu is the son of Shiva. But Ganesh is son of Rudra.

Comment: See, i am talking here about tattvas. The right side of shiva is purush tattva and left side is prakriti tattva. In BVP also ganesha is called as Krishna. And Kartik is always called as Agni. The whole universe is Agni and Soma tattva. So, Kartik created from Rudra is Purush tattva but with the shakti given to him as vel he also got prakriti tattva. Same ganesha was created by parvati so was prakriti tattva but with elephant head given to him he also got purusha tattva.

Comment: You have said that at the end of maha kalpa shiv and lady vishnu (uma) remains. Yes, that's true but they remain as Ardhanareshwara which is neutral gender as shiv shakti are one and same.

Comment: So, Purush and Prakriti are the same ?

Comment: Yes Purusha and Prakriti. Are the same but Purusha is dorment as an enjoyer and witness and Prakriti (aka maya) is the creater of the whole universe. For, example a husband only gives seeds but its the wife who creates the baby while purusha witness it and enjoys the baby. Same. Purusha is idle the feelings of creation within him his prakriti or his shakti. But ultimately the being and his feelings are one only. Word is prakriti as it is physical where as the meaning is purusha as its without any form. So, an illiterate person will see the Prakriti word only but can't know its meaning.

Comment: Same through knowledge one can understand that the word implies that meaning. So, both the the word and meaning are same.

Comment: Does Prakriti also enjoy the creation ? Because wife also enjoys the child.

Comment: Offcourse she does. That's why everyone is called born out of Prakriti.