# Ganesha is son of Parvati or Sati

Tags: ganesha, parvati

Ganesha is considered son of Parvati. However in Sankastahara Chaturthi vrata Katha it says Ganesha instructed his "mother" Parvati (daughter of Himavat), while doing her penance, to perform the vrata and attain Shiva as her husband. The story says Parvati did so and got Shiva as her husband.
It means Ganesha was there before Parvati and Shiva marriage. Does it mean his birth was when Parvati was Sati/Dakshayini?

Comment: Deities are mentioned in cases obviously before their birth a lot. It probably refers to their unmanifested forms a lot of the time.

Comment: Ganesha/Ganapati is a post...someone was Ganesha/Ganapati even before Parvatii's son..Shiva-Parvati worshiped Ganesha/Ganapati in their marriage too..and there are many Ganesha (diff in each kalpa) and we hv diff stories related to how he lost his head (e.g Shiva cutt off or due to Shani's vakra drasti etc.)..https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21655/12304